# Como paro esse loop while em javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Estou tentando criar um loop até que uma conexão com a internet esteja disponivel, porem não consigo parar o loop e continuar o script, tentei 'break' mas não se aplica nesse caso.**

```
const dns = require('dns');

async function testeonline() {
  while (true) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    dns.lookup('www.google.com', async function (err, addresses) {
        
    if (addresses){
        console.log('Online');
        //break
    }
    if(err){
        console.log('Offline');
    }
  });
 }
}

testeonline();
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu vejo dois possíveis problemas aqui.

O primeiro é que talvez essa não seja a melhor abordagem pro que você pretende. Só que é difícil opinar porque você deu poucas informações sobre o que está realmente tentando implementar. Se você está tentando fazer o que eu imagino que esteja, pode ser que valha a pena pesquisar sobre eventos, talvez até usar um `EventEmitter`.

O segundo problema é que você, claramente, tem dificuldades com `Promises`. Te recomendo dar uma atenção especial pra isso nos estudos porque é realmente um assunto bem importante. (pro seu código funcionar, você deveria ter envolvido o `dns.lookup` em uma `Promise`).

Eu montei um código funcional para você usar como base.

```
const dns = require('dns');

function sleep(timeMs) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeMs));
}

function isOffline() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    dns.lookup('www.google.com', async (error) => (
      error ? resolve(true) : resolve(false)
    ));
  });
}

async function waitForOnlineStatus() {
  while (await isOffline()) {
    console.log('Is offline...');
    await sleep(2000);
  }

  console.log('Is online... loop ended!');
}

waitForOnlineStatus();
```

Comment: Foi uma forma diferente mas serviu o propósito, valeu :)

Answer (score -4):

Voce poderia tentar usar uma variavel de controle ao inves de verificar diretamente:

```
let connected = false;

while (connect == false) {
   
   await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));

   const callback = (err, addresses) => {

      if (addresses){ connected=true };

      if(err){ console.log('error') };

   }

   dns.lookup('www.google.com', callback())

};
```

não tive tempo de testar, mas acredito que funcione